# Beta Apps on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I have developed an app that integrates with Google Drive. It makes use of the sharing features. Is there a good way for me to beta test this app while still allowing the same experience as an app in the store? I would like to iron out any bugs and performance issues before releasing to the general public.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The app doesn't need to published in the store in order for it to be installed, simple include the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install` scope when prompting the user for authorization ([more information here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/install)). Once you are ready to publish, there also [ways to test your listing](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/listing#create_a_url_to_test_the_listing) before you make it available to everyone.

Comment: Thanks. How does it work with sharing? When I share the app with someone who doesn't have it, they don't see an option to install the app.

Comment: You just need your app to initiate the OAuth2 flow, and then they will be prompted.

Comment: I think I have a similar problem understanding the flow with sharing. If I share my real-time document with someone who doesn't have the app installed it won't launch my app so I can prompt them for the drive.install scope. Instead it just says preview not available. They are given an opportunity to browse for the app. But that assumes my app is in the store and they can find it. :(

Comment: Yeah I'm in a similar predicament. Sharing just doesn't seem to work if the app is not in the store.

Comment: Even if the application is eventually placed in the store that still assumes the user who received this shared document knows they need to install an app and which app they need to install.

If you look at the file properties in Drive it says what application created it. It would be ideal if Google Drive used this information to prompt the user something similar to:

"You don't have an application installed to edit this type of document. This file was created with application XYZ. Install application XYZ to edit this document?"

Comment: Did you configure the person who you are trying to share with as a Beta tester in the Google Play Developer Console? https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en